# Android: Is there a downside to always using postInvalidate() instead of invalidate()?

Tags: android

I understand that `postInvalidate()` is for non-UI threads. However calling `postInvalidate()` in the UI thread seems harmless and effectively equivalent. (The cost difference seems negligible.)

There is an advantage to always using `postInvalidate()`: you'll never get a crash when your code containing `invalidate()` one day makes its way into a non-UI thread. So why bother with `invalidate()`?